# Information required for Mysql secure installation

Tags: mysql, linux, database, bash

Have a good day all,

I need to Install Mysql in secure way on RHEL7 so for this as i've studied the offcial mysql documents the recommended way to do the installation is by rpm packages provided by MySQL.
For this we need root privileges to install rpm.I've installed the rpm's successfully through root user.Now i've some doubts like

1. After installing MySQL do we need to have root access for day to day tasks performs by dba admin?How can we manage with non-root user like MySQL after that?
2. I test few things like:
    a. once after Installation a mysql user and group got created by Mysql-server rpm and after doing [sudo -u mysql /bin/bash] I'm in with mysql user.But is there any password set for this mysql user?

   b. For more testing i uninstalled the MySQL database and do manually create mysql user and group and set a password and then installed MySQL.
   With root user i'm able to start/stop the services successfully.
   With mysql user if i try to start i get an error like

`Starting MySQL:                                            [  OK  ]
touch: cannot touch '/var/lock/subsys/mysqld\': Permission denied]`

`ps -ef | grep mysql`

tells that mysqld_safe and mysqld are running under mysql account.

So here i edit the file /etc/init.d/mysqld and then i locate lockfile=/var/lock/subsys/$prog and changed it to lockfile=/var/lib/mysql/$prog where mysql user have complete access and this solve my problem.So is this a recommended way?

3. /usr/bin/ have the mysql binaries like mysqladmin,mysqldump owned by root and this should be.So in future if i don't count root user
   then do this mysql user will be able to do all the operations required.In all these cases I've not consider using sudo.

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question are probably convered by the documentation, anyway:

1. No, you don't need root user for the day by day operation performed by the DBAs, you  just need to create a MySql user with all the permissions (see the grant MySql command)
2. a) normally not if you use *sudo* but the actual mysql user usually cannot login (in the passwd file the shell should be `/bin/false`.
   b) no, just use the distro way, so install the RPM and you are fine. Or use a manual way, but I think is harder on the long run (you cannot use any of the automatism offered by the distro)
3. Every user can use these commands, without sudo or any special privileges.

Since you are not saying anything about, I'd like to point to some other actions you can do to secure your DB:

1. set the host(s) that can connect to the db, and allow only it(them). If you need to connect from more that few host, you can work with the subnet mask
2. give each MySql user all but only the privileges it need to do the work and only on the databases he need. Only exception the DBAs, which obviously need to access to all the databases.
3. where possible use a different user/password from the systems ones. If you rlogin is john, your Mysql user and password should be different.
4. if possible, after the installation and the creation of a DBA level user, disable the access from root

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks for the valuable information Gianluca.How you suggest restarting mysql services using mysql user.                                                 [root@localhost tmp]# sudo -u mysql /bin/bash
bash-4.1$ sudo service mysqld stop

bash-4.1$ sudo service mysqld start
Starting mysqld:                                           [  OK  ]
touch: cannot touch `/var/lock/subsys/mysqld': Permission denied
bash-4.1$ whoami
mysql                                          bash-4.1$ sudo service mysqld start
[sudo] password for mysql:

Comment: You just need to edit the config file to have the /var/lock/subsys/mysqld file in a directory owned by the mysq user